# How to pass a function to a service in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, delegates, typescript, this

I have a service in angular like this that calls a webapi method:

```
export class FormulasService extends ServiceBase{
    constructor(){super();}

    renameFormula(id:string, name:string):ng.IPromise<any>{
        var cmd = {id:id, name:name};
        return this.executeCommand('RenameFormula', cmd);
    }
}
```

Now i have a component tha is common in all modules, so it takes a function as parameter:

```
export class RenameModalCtrl extends ControllerBase{
    static $inject=['viewModel']
    constructor(private viewModel:RenameModalModel){
        super();
    }
    saveChanges(){
        this.viewModel.serviceFunction(this.viewModel.id, this.viewModel.name);
    }
}
```

And it's model:

```
export class RenameModalModel{
    constructor(
        public model:any, 
        public serviceMethod:(id:string, name:string)=>ng.IPromise<any>)
}
```

The view:

```
...
<input class="form-control" ng-model="modal.viewModel.model.name" />
<button type="submit" ng-click="modal.saveChanges()">Save Changes</button>
...
```

The viewModel is resolved in the resolve phase of angular.ui.bootstrap.modal.
I use the Controler-As syntax so the modal in view is the RenameModalCtrl.

```
rename()
    {
        var modalInstance = this.$modal.open({
            animation: true,
            controller: 'renameModalCtrl as modal',
            templateUrl: 'renameModal.html',
            resolve: {
                viewModel: new RenameModalModel(this.itemModel, this.formulasService.renameFormula)                    
            }
        });
    }
```

Now this all works, except in service. in the service the 'this' is the actual model, not the service. so it fails on the line: `this.executeCommand('RenameFormula', cmd);`

How to fix this?
Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the => syntax for class methods to bind to the correct "this" reference, rewrite renameFormula like this:

```
renameFormula = (id: string, name: string): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var cmd = { id: id, name: name };
    return this.executeCommand('RenameFormula', cmd);
}
```

There's more details on this here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript